# Configure 'bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller' Helm chart to use pre-existing load balancer

Tags: kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, bitnami

I have an AWS EKS cluster and I am using the Bitnami [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller/#installing-the-chart) Helm chart to handle ingress. This works well for the most part, but I have encountered an issue due to the use of CloudFormation to manage the EKS cluster, VPC, node groups, etc.

The issue is related to the load balancer that is created by the chart - if it exists, I can't delete the CloudFormation stack that was used to create the EKS cluster, VPC, etc. This is because the load balancer is using a network interface that has been assigned public IP, so several network resources cannot be deleted.

Currently I'm installing the vanilla chart, with no values.

```
helm upgrade nginx GitHub/nginx-ingress-controller --install --namespace nginx --create-namespace
```

What I'm hoping is that it's possible to create the load balancer in the same CloudFormation stack and tell the nginx-ingress-controller chart to use/configure that one through the use of values, rather than have it create a new one.

Looking at the documentation I can't see any obvious reference to this, but I'm not an expert on nginx and I'm fairly new to Helm, so hopefully I'm missing something.

As a shot to nothing, I have tried to create a load balancer and assign the same tags that would be assigned to the automatically created one, hoping that the chart would see that and use that load balancer, but sadly it's not that simple!

---

#### Update

I have discovered the values `service.nodePorts` and `service.externalIPs`. `.nodePorts` is honoured, but `.externalIPs` seems to have two issues -

1. When the load balancer is created, it's DNS name is set as the external IP of the **nginx-nginx-ingress-controller** service. However, when I try and pass the DNS name of a pre-existing load balancer the Helm upgrade fails because the DNS name is not a valid IPv4/IPv6 IP address.
2. Any valid value I enter, such as the public IP of the load balancer, is ignored, and a new load balancer is created anyway.

Comment: Would it make sense to provide the already existing DNS IP address? Or this gets ignored as well?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already tried that, but sadly it's ignored. I've updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Did you try with the loadbalancerIP value of the chart?

Comment: Oh, I'd missed that one because it's commented out in values.yaml.
Sadly thought, using it gives an error and the nginx service is stuck in 'Pending'.
`Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: LoadBalancerIP cannot be specified for AWS ELB`

Comment: Then I think it would be worth checking with the EKS support to see how we can map a service to an existing ELB